# MSMQ Generic Messaging

Tags: .net-2.0, msmq

I'm thinking of creating a generic message queue to handle various inter-process messages.  (WCF is not an option at this point.)  So, rather than have 10-15 different queues for specific messages I'd have 1 queue that is a 'catch-all'.

Obviously sending messages to this queue is a not a problem.  Each recipient would listen to the queue for new messages then 'peek' them, but I'm looking for a clean/efficient way to do this.  By clean I mean a method that does not require each and every recipient to read the body of each and every message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use System.Messaging.Message.AppSpecific (Integer) to specify a recipient.